# Creating Composite primary keys in a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two tables that are connected via a join table in a many-to-many relationship in the Entity Framework.  I need to add a composite primary key in the join table for the two columns that are related to the joined tables via standard foreign keys but I'm sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your join table has a composite key on both foreign keys, the Entity Framework designer in VS2008/2010 should pick up on that.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  ColumnFK1  int,
  ColumnFK2  int

PRIMARY KEY (ColumnFK1, ColumnFK2)
)
```

If the table is already created you can modify the primary key in Management Studio.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's what I figured, the designer view of the EDM shows the many-to-many relationship.  But when I try to update the related entities, it bugs out with the error: 

"Unable to update the EntitySet '' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists"

Comment: I want to modify it in the Management Studio, but I don't know how to open the .mdf file that my tables are in.

Comment: Never mind, I was able to open it using instructions from this link: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071221220201AA9W2mG.  Thanks Dave, I was able to resolve the error, what a hassle.  Hope my experience can save others time.  The following link also helped to shed light on the error I was getting: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/109/ASP.NET-MVC-Entity-Framework-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-Many-INSERTS